# iCloud and Google Drive Integration in React Native App

Tags: sqlite, react-native, google-drive-api, icloud

I'm trying to integrate iCloud and Google Drive into a React Native App. App basically stores user documents in SQLite. Every document has a couple of strings and a maximum of 2 images. I want to upload them to iCloud and Google Drive in iOS and Google Drive in Android as Cloud backup that can be restored if app gets deleted.

So far,I couldn't find any proper documentation, SDKs or Third Party Libraries that perform these functions. All the third party libraries I found are old by a few years and not maintained.

Could you guys please share some links to resources or tutorials. I have been searching for a few days and I couldn't find anything recent.

Comment: got any luck with that ?

Comment: Nope. Eventually had to create a new React Native module with separate implementation in Native iOS and Android. Work is still ongoing.

Comment: You should check a cloud solution like [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). It has document based database, file storage and a flexible user authentication system. It's not free but it has large limits on free tier. There is also a great RN library to use it [`react-native-firebase`](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/).

Answer (score 4):

You can Achieve it using following RN third party packages.

For icloud [RN icloud sync](https://github.com/npomfret/react-native-cloud-fs)

For google drive [RN Google Drive sync](https://github.com/RobinBobin/react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper)

**copyToiCloud**

```
const sourceUri = {uri: 'https://example.com/bar.pdf'};
const destinationPath = "/docs/info.pdf";
const mimeType = null;
const scope = 'visible';

RNCloudFs.copyToCloud({
  sourcePath: sourceUri, 
  targetPath: destinationPath, 
  mimeType: mimeType, 
  scope: scope
})
  .then((path) => {
    console.log("it worked", path);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.warn("it failed", err);
  })
```

Google Drive Api

```
 const contents = "My text file contents";
 // or
 const contents = [10, 20, 30];


     GDrive.files.createFileMultipart(
         contents,
         "corresponding mime type", {
             parents: ["root"],
             name: "My file"
         },
         isBase64);
```

For more information check it on the link. Because I am not working on these api's

Comment: is it possible to store sqlite document in icloud?